# AngularJS 10 $digest() iterations reached when list show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

my js code is :

```
// 在变更分布的时候，重新获取数据条目
$scope.reGetProducts = function(){
        // 发送给后台的请求数据
        $scope.model.cpage=$scope.paginationConf.currentPage;
        $scope.model.len=$scope.paginationConf.itemsPerPage;

        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/sysConfigManage/querySysConfigList.action',
            data    : $scope.model,  // pass in data as strings
            headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        }).success(function(data){
            // 变更分页的总数
            $scope.paginationConf.totalItems = data.total;
            // 变更列表条目
            $scope.items = data.rows;
        });
    };

    // 配置分页基本参数
    $scope.paginationConf = {
        currentPage: 0,
        itemsPerPage: 10
    };
    $scope.model = {};
    $scope.items = {};
    // 通过$watch currentPage和itemperPage 当他们一变化的时候，重新获取数据条目
    $scope.$watch('paginationConf.currentPage + paginationConf.itemsPerPage',$scope.reGetProducts);
```

and html  is

```
<tr bindonce ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="getDetaile(item.ID)">详情</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"  ng-click="del(item.ID)">删除</button>
    </td>
    <td bo-text="item.NAME"></td>
    <td bo-text="item.CODE"></td>
    <td bo-text="item.VALUE"></td>
    <td bo-text="item.MEMO"></td>
</tr>
```

why that errors course  ,please help me,,,..

Comment: is the $watch working when you only use it on 'paginationConf.currentPage' or 'paginationConf.itemsPerPage'?

Comment: no hint from your snippet, but usually this error is caused by a dead loop of `$watch` which means you watch A and change A in the watch handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 $scope.$watch('paginationConf.currentPage + paginationConf.itemsPerPage',$scope.reGetProducts);
```

You are watching on an operation, which will be never stable. On each digest call angular compares the result of the computation and compares two new objects.

Read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig

Therefore angular cannot determine a stable model. You can easily write that:

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['paginationConf.currentPage', 'paginationConf.itemsPerPage'], $scope.reGetProducts);
```